# Azure storage account with SAS token

Tags: azure-blob-storage

I have storage account that contains one container, When I am generating SAS token from Portal without IP restriction it is working fine but when I am generating SAS token from portal with IP restriction, then it is not working. I am providing the Vnet IP range in the IP range column. But when I am trying to access through Azure Explorer which is installed in one of the VM inside the Vnet address space, it is giving error "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this source IP". 
Vnet Ip range -192.168.0.0/24 and VM private IP is 192.168.0.68. [image]

I do not know from where this 100.74.202.44 source IP is coming. VM private is 192.168.0.68 and its public IP is also different i.e 52.34.X.X.
Let me know what I am doing wrong here or this is Bug?

Comment: storage accounts are not accessed internally, so only externally, you cannot access azure storage account using internal ip address of your vm, so no sense of giving SAS token for internal IP addresses

Comment: could you explain in more generic ?

Comment: I have tried giving public IP as well but getting same error.

Comment: There is option to provide IP range while creating SAS token, so how could anyone give range for public IP? and even if we provide public IP then what is the use for restricting IP while generating SAS token. These are the things that are coming to my mind

Comment: If it is useful, please help to mark it as answer that will help more communities who have same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VM private is 192.168.0.68 and its public IP is also different i.e 52.34.X.X. Let me know what I am doing wrong here or this is Bug?

Base on my knowledge, it is the internal IP that VM get from the Azure DataCenter by DHCP. On the Azure classic portal we can get the internal ip from the Classic VM Dashboard as following:

[image]

But in the Azure new portal, I can't find it out.
When try to visit the Azure storage from the Azure VM then it seems that via Azure internal Ip 100.x.x.x.
 So please have a try to add this IP for restriction to generate SAS token, then it will work.

Comment: so what you are saying is if we will access storage from VM then it is taking 100.X.X.X IP and I need to provide this IP while generating SAS token. but suppose I have 5 VM in Vnet then how to provide IP range? if it is not taking internal IP or public IP

Comment: As I know storage IP restriction just allow us to add single IP or IP range. If we want to add 5 VMs in the restriction for storage SAS  then we need to provide IP range that contains internal IPs of 5 VMs.